# How to specify default values when using Jackson with Mr Bean?

Tags: java, json, jackson, default-value

As far as I understand, Jackson has no built-in way to handle default values (for when a property is unspecified) other than just assigning those field values when instantiating your object. For example:

```
class Person {
    String firstName = "John";
    String lastName = "Smith";
}
```

Now if I try to parse JSON with one or more of the fields undefined, they'll still have the default value.

The problem is that I'm using [Mr Bean](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-base/tree/master/mrbean), which materializes abstract classes or interfaces. For example:

```
interface Person {
    String getFirstName();
    String getLastName();
}
```

Because they're just abstract methods, there's no way to set a default with Java syntax, and I haven't found any way to do it with Jackson. Is there some solution I've missed?